# How to compile different extension files as C++ in Visual Studio C++ 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compilation, file-extension, build-rules

In my Visual Studio 2010 project I have files with .mm file extension, that need to be compiled as normal C++ files. Is there a way to make a build rule for new extensions or something like that? In VS 2008 there were options for that, but they are gone in 2010.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an individual file: Right click on the file > Properties > Configuration Properties - General > Item Type : C/C++ compiler.

In general for a project: [How to: Select the Files to Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171454%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), [Walkthrough: Using MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393573%28VS.100%29.aspx), [Walkthrough: Creating an MSBuild Project File from Scratch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576348%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You can set how the file will be compiled for any unknown file type by:

1. Right click on the file in your solution explorer
2. Click on properties on the file
3. Go to the General tab
4. Set exclude from build to: No
5. Set Item type: to C/C++ compiler

Answer (score 0):

- in vs2008 you can set in project properties (simply select extensions that should be treated as C++ via menu)
- in vs2010 and vs2012 I've never been able to configure this properly, I tried all these walkthroughs, tutorials and tricks. They simply do not work as expected and my *.mm files are not compiled.